# *ngFor do Angular sempre retorna o primeiro item da lista

Tags: angular

Estou criando uma loja online usando Angular, tenho a página */produtos* que me mostra todos os produtos de uma lista que fica dentro do arquivo 'produtos.ts', mas quando clico em qualquer um dos produtos dessa página, ele me redireciona sempre para o 1º item dessa lista.

Por exemplo, eu clico no produto "monitor" com id 2, ele me redireciona para *localhost:4200/produtos/2* mas abre o produto de id 1. O mesmo acontece com TODOS os itens da lista, ele sempre me mostra o 1º item (sei disso pois comentei o 1º item e aí ele começou a mostrar o item de id 2, então o problema é sempre o 1º item mesmo, e não o id).

**produtos.ts**

```
export interface IProduto {
    id: number;
    descricao: string;
    preco: number;
    descricaoPreco: string;
    quantidadeEstoque: number;
    imagem: string;
}

export interface IProdutoCarrinho extends IProduto {
    quantidade: number;
}

export const produtos: IProduto[] = [
    { id: 1, descricao: "Mouse gamer", preco: 439.00, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/mouse-3.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 2, descricao: "Monitor muito bom", preco: 1200.50, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/monitor-1.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 3, descricao: "Teclado excelente", preco: 749.99, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/teclado-1.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 4, descricao: "Fone para quem joga FPS", preco: 599.99, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/fone-de-ouvido-2.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 5, descricao: "Fone de ouvido", preco: 299.99, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/fone-de-ouvido-1.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 6, descricao: "Fone de ouvido bom", preco: 399.99, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/fone-de-ouvido-3.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 7, descricao: "HD 1TB", preco: 499.99, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/hd.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 8, descricao: "Combo de placa de vídeos", preco: 18449.99, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/placa-video.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 9, descricao: "Processador Ryzen", preco: 1000, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/processador.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 10, descricao: "Notebook bom", preco: 2500, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/laptop-1.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 11, descricao: "Notebook excelente", preco: 4500, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/laptop-2.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 12, descricao: "Mouse barato", preco: 20, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/mouse-1.png", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 13, descricao: "Mouse ótimo", preco: 200, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/mouse-2.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 14, descricao: "Mouse pequeno", preco: 50, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/mouse-4.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
    { id: 15, descricao: "Teclado bom", preco: 159.99, descricaoPreco: "À vista no PIX", imagem: "/assets/teclado-2.jpg", quantidadeEstoque: 10 },
]
```

**produtos.component.html**

```
<section class="product-list">
    <div class="product-list__card" *ngFor="let produto of produtos">
        <a routerLink="/produtos/{{produto.id}}" class="product-list__link">
            <img [src]="produto.imagem">
            <h2 class="product-item__name">
                {{ produto.descricao }}
            </h2>
            <p class="product-item__price">
                {{ produto.preco | currency: "BRL" }}
            </p>
            <p class="product-item__price-description">
                {{ produto.descricaoPreco }}
            </p>
            <button class="product-item__buy-button" type="button">Comprar</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

**detalhes-produto.component.html**

```
<section class="product__container">
    <div class="product-image__container">
        <img [src]="produto?.imagem" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="product-description__container">
        <h2 class="product__name">{{ produto?.descricao }}</h2>
        <h3 class="product__price">{{ produto?.preco | currency: "BRL" }}</h3>
        <p>Estoque disponivel:</p>
        <label>
            Quantidade:
            <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="quantidade" min="1">
            unidade(s)
        </label>
        <p class="product__availability">
            {{ produto?.quantidadeEstoque }} unidade(s) em estoque
        </p>
        <button (click)="adicionarAoCarrinho()">Adicionar ao carrinho</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

**produtos-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DetalhesProdutoComponent } from './detalhes-produto/detalhes-produto.component';
import { ProdutosComponent } from './produtos.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ProdutosComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: DetalhesProdutoComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProdutosRoutingModule { }
```

**detalhes-produto.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CarrinhoService } from 'src/app/carrinho.service';
import { NotificacaoService } from 'src/app/notificacao.service';
import { IProduto, IProdutoCarrinho } from 'src/app/produtos';
import { ProdutosService } from 'src/app/produtos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detalhes-produto',
  templateUrl: './detalhes-produto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detalhes-produto.component.css']
})
export class DetalhesProdutoComponent implements OnInit {
  produto: IProduto | undefined;
  quantidade = 1;

  constructor(
    private produtosService: ProdutosService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private notificacaoService: NotificacaoService,
    private carrinhoService: CarrinhoService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const routeParams = this.route.snapshot.paramMap;
    const produtoId = Number(routeParams.get('id'));
    this.produto = this.produtosService.getOne(produtoId);
  }

  adicionarAoCarrinho() {
    this.notificacaoService.notificar("O produto foi adicionado ao carrinho");
    const produto: IProdutoCarrinho = {
      ...this.produto!,
      quantidade: this.quantidade
    }
    this.carrinhoService.adicionarAoCarrinho(produto);
  }

}
```

**produtos.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduto, produtos } from './produtos';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProdutosService {
  produtos: IProduto[] = produtos;

  constructor() { }

  getAll() {
    return this.produtos;
  }

  getOne(produtoId: number) {
    return this.produtos.find(produto => produto.id = produtoId);
  }
}
```

**exemplo do item de id 1 (mouse) sendo mostrado quando clico no item de id 2 (deveria ser um monitor):**
[imagem que mostra o erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCZSo.png)

Comment: Mostra o conteúdo de `detalhes-produto.component.ts`.

Comment: acabei de adicionar, é o ultimo item antes da imagem :)

Comment: Parece que está tudo correto. Acredito que o problema esteja no método `getOne` da `ProdutosService`, se importaria de mostrá-la?

Comment: acabei de adicionar, tbm no final do post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No método `getOne` da classe `ProdutosService`, vc deveria fazer uma comparação, mas esta fazendo uma atribuíção.

Para corrigir, troque isto:

```
this.produtos.find(produto => produto.id = produtoId);
```

Por isto:

```
this.produtos.find(produto => produto.id === produtoId);
```

Comment: funcionou!!! muuuuito obrigada! eu nunca teria achado esse erro sozinha